# Set default sound device output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I own a pair of usb powered speakers, and I am having trouble finding how to set the usb speakers as the default output. I found the setting where you can switch the outputs but no where to asssign a default. I took screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Here http://askubuntu.com/questions/158908/how-can-i-force-a-preferred-sound-output-device-to-be-used

Answer (score 18):

You can first view your current default audio device by typing:

```
pactl stat
```

And with

```
pactl list
```

you can view all your devices.

And with this command

```
echo "set-default-sink alsa_output.Headset" | pacmd
```

you can set the default device.

Comment: seems no matter what I do, the output is always: "Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information." Is there a confirmation of any sort?

Comment: @Zlatty, I got that same message, but followed it up with `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start` which seems to persist the change.

Comment: Ah excellent. It had seemed to work after a restart so a hooray for the both of us.

Comment: in 2022 use `pactl info` (not `pactl stat`)