# How can I force a preferred sound output device to be used?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

In my sound settings interface, there are two devices for sound output:

[image: sound settings]

Both refer to the same physical device, which is a network sound device.

Both work, but only with the second one, `Simultaneous output to Kenwook Audio Device Digital Stereo (IEC958) on mythbuntu@mythbuntu`, does the output volume respond to being changed. The first one always plays at the same level, and ignores volume settings.

Every time I boot, the first one is selected. How can I make it so the second one is the default and the first one is disabled or at least never selected?

I've uploaded to Pastebin the output from [`pacmd list-sinks`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1072719/) and the contents of my [`default.pa`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1072704) file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default audio device from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entry **"Simultaneous output to..."** tells us that in our setup the pulseaudio [module-combine-sink](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-combine-sink), or a network combined device from  module-tunnel-sink was loaded.

This can be done in an entry in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, in `~/.pulse/default.pa` or manually, e.g. by a script. It may have been loaded in the `default.pa` used by the daemon or from an application that provides the network audio.

Changing the default output sink to this combined sink should be done **after** we loaded the sink. In addition we need to know the name of this sink which may be the default `"combined"` or any other name.

#### Find out the name of the sink

To find out the name given we can list all installed sinks on our sytem with the command

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

#### Change the default output sink to e.g. "combined"

To change the default sink we can issue the following command

```
pacmd set-default-sink "combined"  # or any other sink name or index
```

This command can also be issued from a script.

#### Make this sink permanent on start of the pulseaudio daemon

To define a default sink permanently on startup of the daemon we uncomment/add the following line at the end of our `default.pa`

```
set-default-sink "combined"  # or any other sink name
```

In case we want this for all users we edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, in case its for one user only we may copy (and edit) the `default.pa` to `~/.pulse/`. Make sure that this sink was loaded before.

Comment: My `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file does not have a `load-module module-combine-sink` line in it. Is it safe to just add it? Does it matter where?

Comment: @DaveMG: is a sink "combined" listed on `pacmd list-sinks`? Also see if we have loaded the combine module with `pacmd list-modules`. We should not load that module twice!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment. I've now pasted the output of pacmd list-sinks to pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1072719/ And I've posted my default.pa file to http://paste.ubuntu.com/1072704 In the output of `pacmd list-sinks`, there is a line that says `tunnel.remote.sink = "combined"`. Is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: @DaveMG: thank you for posting the details. We can see now, that the combined sink is a network tunnel sink in your case. Edited answer to reflect this. We don't know when this sink is loaded but in your case the "combined" sink won't work. Try with `tunnel.mythbuntu.local.combined`, or just the index `2` in your case. If a default.pa entry fails you may have to do that from a script (e.g. in autostart).

Comment: thank you for your time and effort in providing this information. I'm not quite sure what to do with this answer now. Since fixing my Flash/Pulseaudio problem, the whole setup is different now, and I'm not sure this applies anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Get sink names:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Set default sink:

```
echo "set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Dell_Dell_AC511_USB_SoundBar-00.iec958-stereo" | pacmd
```