# PulseAudio card is re-enabled when I unlock the screen after disabling that card

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

I have two audio devices on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine: Built-in Audio and a USB sound device, and I only want to use the USB device; I don't need the Built-in Audio at all, and I'd like to disable it (because then I never have to worry about selecting a sound device in video conferencing apps and the like). I can disable the Built-in Audio device in PulseAudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`) by setting "Built-in Audio" to "off", and I can also do this same action from the command line with `pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0 off` and that all works. However, if I lock the screen and then unlock it again, that card gets re-enabled! How can I set it to off so that it *stays* off?

Comment: according to the comment here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145135/set-default-sound-device-output settings seem to become persistant after  `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start`

Comment: @db429 sadly that has not helped: I have killed and restarted pulseaudio and the problem still occurs; a disabled Built-in Audio device still gets re-enabled after locking and unlocking the screen.

Comment: makes `pacmd suspend-sink alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0 1` and `pacmd suspend-source alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0 1`any difference? and i guess you had a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback/72076#72076

Comment: @db429 pacmd suspend-sink alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0 1
No sink found by this name or index.
Does the sink need to be a different name from the card?

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake .. just copied your entry from your question;  `pacmd list-sources` and `pacmd list-sinks`would be the commands to find the proper sinks and sources and there is also `pacmd list-cards`

Comment: @db429 sadly this doesn't help. (The command I used is "pacmd suspend-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1 {0,1}", tried with both 0 and 1, and that doesn't seem to change anything in pavucontrol's Configuration panel.)